# Preenchendo data.frame a partir de outro data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu tenho dois data.frames: "a" e "df"

```
a <- data.frame(x=seq(13,37,1),rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),each=5),seq(21,105,21))
colnames(a)<-c("values","date","term")

b<-data.frame(x,21,42,63,84,105)
colnames(b)<-c("date","term21","term42","term63","term84","term105")
m <- as.matrix(b)
m[m>20] <- 0
df <- as.data.frame(m)


head(a)

  values date term
1     13    1   21
2     14    1   42
3     15    1   63
4     16    1   84
5     17    1  105
6     18    2   21

head(df)

  date term21 term42 term63 term84 term105
1    1      0      0      0      0       0
2    2      0      0      0      0       0
3    3      0      0      0      0       0
4    4      0      0      0      0       0
5    5      0      0      0      0       0
```

O que eu fiz foi transpor o data frame "a" e eliminar as linhas "date" repetidas.

Agora, quero preencher o data.frame "df" com seus valores, ou seja, no final tenho que ter:

```
date  term21  term42  term63  term84  term105
    1   13      14      15      16       17
    2   18      19      20      21       22 
    3   23      24      25      26       27 
    4   28      29      30      31       32
    5   33      34      35      36       37
```

Há alguma forma mais funcional de fazer isso. Partindo apenas do data.frame "a" ??

Pq meu data.frame "a" original é  gigantesco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você quer fazer na verdade é passar o data frame para o formato `wide` ("pivotear"). Você pode fazer isso com a função `dcast` do pacote `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(a, date~term, value.var = "values")
  date 21 42 63 84 105
1    1 13 14 15 16  17
2    2 18 19 20 21  22
3    3 23 24 25 26  27
4    4 28 29 30 31  32
5    5 33 34 35 36  37
```

Você também pode fazer com `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
a %>% spread(term, values)
  date 21 42 63 84 105
1    1 13 14 15 16  17
2    2 18 19 20 21  22
3    3 23 24 25 26  27
4    4 28 29 30 31  32
5    5 33 34 35 36  37
```