# Como transpor linhas para colunas em um data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Possuo uma série temporal com dados diários de precipitação entre 1961 e 2017, conforme exemplo abaixo. Preciso agrupar esses dados por mês ao longo dos anos. Consegui transpor a coluna "mes" do data frame e preencher com os valores da coluna "prec", utilizando a função `dcast`, a exemplo da pergunta contida em [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110368/preenchendo-data-frame-a-partir-de-outro-data-frame).

`ID dia mes  ano    prec
1   21  ago 1961    NA
2   22  ago 1961    0.00
3   23  ago 1961    1.00
4   24  ago 1961    0.00
5   25  ago 1961    0.00
6   26  ago 1961    0.00
7   27  ago 1961    0.00
8   28  ago 1961    0.00
9   29  ago 1961    0.00
10  30  ago 1961    NA
11  31  ago 1961    0.00
12  1   set 1961    0.00
13  2   set 1961    0.00
14  3   set 1961    0.00
15  4   set 1961    0.00
16  5   set 1961    0.00
17  6   set 1961    0.00
18  7   set 1961    0.00
19  8   set 1961    NA
20  9   set 1961    0.00
21  10  set 1961    0.00
22  11  set 1961    0.00
23  12  set 1961    0.00
24  13  set 1961    0.00
25  14  set 1961    0.00
26  15  set 1961    0.00
27  16  set 1961    0.00
28  17  set 1961    0.00
29  18  set 1961    0.00
30  19  set 1961    0.00
31  20  set 1961    0.00
32  21  set 1961    0.00
33  22  set 1961    0.00
34  23  set 1961    0.00
35  24  set 1961    0.00
36  25  set 1961    0.00
37  26  set 1961    0.00
38  27  set 1961    0.00
39  28  set 1961    0.00
40  29  set 1961    0.00
41  30  set 1961    0.00`

Porém, o data frame resultante não apresenta os valores consecutivos de precipitação para cada mês, mas sim blocos de valores em função do ID da tabela, como representado esquematicamente abaixo.

```
ID  jan  fev  ...  ago  set  ...  dez
1                  Na           
2                  0
3                  1
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
11                 0
12                      0
.                       .
.                       .
.                       .
41                      0
42                            0
```

Como consigo resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza se é o que você quer, mas pode tentar usar a biblioteca `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, mes, prec)
```

---

```
   ID dia  ano ago set
1   1  21 1961  NA  NA
2   2  22 1961   0  NA
3   3  23 1961   1  NA
4   4  24 1961   0  NA
5   5  25 1961   0  NA
6   6  26 1961   0  NA
7   7  27 1961   0  NA
8   8  28 1961   0  NA
9   9  29 1961   0  NA
10 10  30 1961  NA  NA
11 11  31 1961   0  NA
12 12   1 1961  NA   0
13 13   2 1961  NA   0
14 14   3 1961  NA   0
15 15   4 1961  NA   0
16 16   5 1961  NA   0
17 17   6 1961  NA   0
18 18   7 1961  NA   0
19 19   8 1961  NA  NA
20 20   9 1961  NA   0
21 21  10 1961  NA   0
22 22  11 1961  NA   0
23 23  12 1961  NA   0
24 24  13 1961  NA   0
25 25  14 1961  NA   0
26 26  15 1961  NA   0
27 27  16 1961  NA   0
28 28  17 1961  NA   0
29 29  18 1961  NA   0
30 30  19 1961  NA   0
31 31  20 1961  NA   0
32 32  21 1961  NA   0
33 33  22 1961  NA   0
34 34  23 1961  NA   0
35 35  24 1961  NA   0
36 36  25 1961  NA   0
37 37  26 1961  NA   0
38 38  27 1961  NA   0
39 39  28 1961  NA   0
40 40  29 1961  NA   0
41 41  30 1961  NA   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a forma mais simples ainda é com a função R base `xtabs`.

```
result <- xtabs( ~ ID + mes, dados)
head(result)
#   mes
#ID  ago set
#  1   1   0
#  2   1   0
#  3   1   0
#  4   1   0
#  5   1   0
#  6   1   0
```

Outra maneira, usando só o R base poderá ser

```
reshape(dados[c(1, 3, 5)], idvar = "ID", timevar = "mes", direction = "wide")
```

E com o pacote `reshape2`,

```
reshape2::dcast(dados, ID ~ mes)
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(ID = 1:41, dia = c(21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), mes = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ago", "set"), class = "factor"), 
    ano = c(1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 
    1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 
    1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 
    1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 
    1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L), prec = c(NA, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "dia", "mes", "ano", "prec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-41L))
```

Comment: A função xtabs funcionou em parte, pois as linhas contendo NA foram suprimidas e eu preciso que elas sejam mantidas. Tem como fazer isso? Tentei seguir o exemplo do help, mas não deu certo também.

Comment: Na verdade, reparei que a função xtabs me da a frequência de medidas. É isso msm? Enquanto eu preciso de uma função que transfira os valores de chuva para as colunas, sendo cada coluna um mes do ano.