# Como inserir linhas em locais específicos num data frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso inserir linhas na coluna "fev" nos dias 30 e 31 que sejam preenchidas com "NA", de modo que os dados contidos nas linhas sejam deslocados para baixo. Tentei `fev$novaLin <-  with(fev, as.integer(d == 30, 31 & fev == NA, NA))`, mas não deu certo pois foi criada uma coluna ao lado da coluna "fev", com indicação dos NAs nos dias 30 e 31 e sem os demais dados. Como minha serie de dados é muito longa, preciso de uma função que automatize esse processo.

Como posso solucionar isso?

`id dia fev
1   1   0.2
2   2   0.1
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   0.9
6   6   0.23
7   7   0
8   8   0
9   9   0
10  10  NA
11  11  NA
12  12  NA
13  13  NA
14  14  10.2
15  15  0
16  16  0
17  17  6.7
18  18  0
19  19  0
20  20  0
21  21  0
22  22  0.3
23  23  0.7
24  24  0
25  25  0
26  26  0
27  27  0
28  28  NA
29  29  NA
30  30  5.3
31  31  0
32  1   40.5
33  2   4.8
34  3   0`

Comment: Está estranho isso. Dados para os dias 30 e 31 de fevereiro é uma boa indicação que os dados ou o pré-processamento estão com problemas. Mas caso seja isso mesmo, o que você espera como resposta para as linhas com `id` acima de 30?

Comment: Sim, o pré-processamento está com problemas pois não consegui transpor meu dataframe original da maneira adequada, conforme havia demonstrado em [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288057/como-transpor-linhas-para-colunas-em-um-data-frame]. Por isso, preciso deslocar os dados de 30 e 31, pois na verdade eles são dos dia 01 e 02 do próximo ano.

Comment: Com base nessa [resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2628/1271) acho melhor você descartar essa pergunta e abrir uma nova pergunta com os dados de fevereiro. Vai ser parecida com a pergunta original, mas paciência. De preferência no lugar de colocar a tabela, coloque o resultado do `dput` como o barradas fez na [resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288176/1271). Continuar o processamento desse modo esta sujeito a propagar erros e vai ser difícil você explicar para alguém o que você fez.